# In promQL, how to max clamp the values of an instant vector with another instant vector

Tags: promql, clamp

Is there a way to achieve that max clamping by passing an instant vector containing corresponding max values for each series?

In promQL, using the function [clamp_max](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#clamp_max), it is possible to clamp the values of an instant vector with a scalar value, but if an instant vector is passed instead of the scalar, you get an error

Using function `scalar()` on that instant vector only works if the instant vector only contains one single value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution for clamping `v` time series with `max_v` series is the following:

```
(v < max_v) or max_v
```

This query works in the following way:

1. The `v < max_v` leaves only values smaller than `max_v`.
2. The `(...) or max_v` fills gaps from the step 1 with `max_v` values.

Answer (score 1):

Given instant vectors v and max_v with the same labels, this makes the trick

```
(v <= bool max_v) * v + (v > bool max_v) * max_v
```

When using comparison operators followed by `bool`, their expressions will return 0 (`false`) or 1 (`true`) for each series accordingly.

Considering the whole expression, for each series, only one term, `(v <= bool max_v)` or `(v > bool max_v)` can be `true`, so for each series it'll return either the value on v or the maximum on max_v.

Answer (score 0):

Less hacky approach:

Consider `v` as initial metric, `max_v` - max clamping vector.
You can use combination of `and` and `or` operators to achieve clamping with instant vector:

```
v and (v < max_v) or max_v
```

Here for every time slot, value from `v` will be taken it its value less than value from `max_v`, otherwise will be taken value from `max_v`.